# Google Sheets App Script failed email send Exception: Request failed for https://docs.google.com returned code 401. Truncated server

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have 5 google sheets all with the same code below and only 1 of them is having this error `Exception: Request failed for https://docs.google.com returned code 401. Truncated server`

```js
//Get active sheets
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

// Base URL this is used to send to the API 
var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/SS_ID/export?".replace("SS_ID", ss.getId());

//Format PDF settig up styling
var url_ext = 'exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf' // export as pdf / csv / xls / xlsx
    + '&size=A4' // paper size legal / letter / A4
    + '&portrait=true' // orientation, false for landscape
    + '&fitw=true&source=labnol' // fit to page width, false for actual size
    + '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false' // hide optional headers and footers
    + '&pagenumbers=false&gridlines=false' // hide page numbers and gridlines
    + '&fzr=false' // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
    + '&gid='; // the sheet's Id

//API to fetch PFD of google sheet
var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + url_ext + sheet.getSheetId(), {                                 
        headers : {
            'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + token
        }
    }).getBlob().setName(sheet.getName() + ".pdf");
sheet_as_pdf_blob_document=response;

// Define your variables here
var beerOrderrecipient="test@test.com";
var beerOrdersubject=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getName();
var beerOrderbody="Hello,\n\nNew items have been added to your Ordered Beer List. Attached is a printable copy of the most up to date list. \n- Have a great day!";
var nameOfSender="Operations";


function sendOrderedSheet() {
  var message = {
   to: beerOrderrecipient,
   subject:beerOrdersubject,
   body: beerOrderbody,
   name: nameOfSender,
   attachments: [sheet_as_pdf_blob_document]
  }  
  MailApp.sendEmail(message);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("The email has been sent thank you!");  
}
```

I'm not sure what makes this one different. If I need to include anything else let me know!

**UPDATE**
I was able to fix the problem. So apparently there was a trigger from a long time ago calling a different function but it never succeeded it automatically went off every day and failed, so I deleted the trigger and its connecting function and everything started to work again!

Comment: @Cooper That's the problem is it works for me on my other sheets just not this sheet. I Submitted a bug report ticket if there is any updates I'll post it here!

Answer (score 2):

I ran it this way:

```
function sendOrderedSheet() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/SS_ID/export?".replace("SS_ID", ss.getId());
  var url_ext = 'exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf' + '&size=A4' + '&portrait=true' + '&fitw=true&source=labnol' + '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false' + '&pagenumbers=false&gridlines=false' + '&fzr=false' + '&gid=';
  var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + url_ext + sheet.getSheetId(), {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
    }
  }).getBlob().setName(sheet.getName() + ".pdf");
  const sheet_as_pdf_blob_document = response;
  var beerOrderrecipient = "myemail";
  var beerOrdersubject = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getName();
  var beerOrderbody = "Hello,\n\nNew items have been added to your Ordered Beer List. Attached is a printable copy of the most up to date list. \n- Have a great day!";
  var nameOfSender = "Operations";
  var message = {
    to: beerOrderrecipient,
    subject: beerOrdersubject,
    body: beerOrderbody,
    name: nameOfSender,
    attachments: [sheet_as_pdf_blob_document]
  }
  MailApp.sendEmail(message);
  //SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("The email has been sent thank you!");  
}
```